# Bad example of parameter estimation?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, parameter-estimation, estimation

Our professor gave us the following example and said that this is a typical one when it comes to parameter estimation.

> A wholesaler receives a shipment of $40,000$ bananas and wants to estimate the portion of spoiled bananas, given by $m$. So he takes a sample of $100$ bananas and counts $5$ spoiled bananas. He decides to use $\frac{5}{100}$ as an estimate for the total portion of spoiled bananas. Is this a good estimate?

---

Taking a sample of $100$ bananas and counting the spoiled ones can be represented by a hypergeometric distributed random variable $X$, so the expected value of the estimator is simply
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{100}\right)= m.
$$
So the estimator is unbiased.

However, this example doesn't make a lot of sense to me. Because usually when performing any estimation we should have a larger sample and here the wholesaler only takes one sample, namely the $100$ bananas. So in my opinion the wholesaler should take more than one sample (of course independent ones) to get an appropriate estimator.

What do you think? Is this just a bad example?

Comment: "good" is subjective.  Here, you could work out the probability that you observed $m$ given a range of probabilities.  Decide if that range is tolerable or not.

Comment: @lulu, but does it make sense at all if we only have one sample?

Comment: $100$ bananas is a relatively small sample, and would be worse if you chose twenty bunches/hands of $5$ bananas each finding that one bunch was spoiled.  But even this would not one sample, but in effect a sample size of $20$

Comment: The fact that there is only one sample isn't lethal on its own...if the sample consisted of $39,999$ bananas, it would be nearly perfect.  It's the size of the sample that matters.

Comment: There are all sorts of sampling, which also can be better or worse. I guess one should assume that the sampling was done the best they could. (E.g. if the shipment came in crates and one of them said "Use By: 1/1/1969" it would be unwise to _not_ take this crate into the sample.) Other than that, I am not sure why you insist on calling it "one" sample, when we are talking about $100$ bananas, after all.

Comment: A random sample text about the types of sampling: https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch01-not.html . Think of all the ways the $100$ bananas could have been chosen. ($10$ independent batches of $10$ bananas, $100$ bananas just grabbed from the first crate you came to, take all the bananas, put them in the line and take every $400$th, etc.) In other words, the problem does not put the restriction on how this "one" sample was chosen. All you know it is of size $100$. (Maybe you only have $100$ test kits for rottenness of bananas?)

Comment: Should also remark that "rottenness" is also subjective.  If I looked at those $100$, would I also see exactly $5$ rotten ones?  Easy to imagine people disagreeing on a few...

Comment: The number of samples isn't important as in this situation you can simply combine them into one large sample. Just the total number of bananas sampled matters. To get some idea as to how "good" the sample is you could for example calculate a 95% confidence interval  for the proportion of bad bananas in the population. Using a normal approximation to the binomial distribution I get confidence limits between .0073 and .093. See for example  https://openstax.org/books/introductory-business-statistics/pages/8-3-a-confidence-interval-for-a-population-proportion

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing explicitly wrong with anything described in the example. There are plenty of missing details which *could* have an impact - for example, the mechanism by which the samples are taken - but as long as we assume that the 100 bananas sampled were not in any way "special" compared to the rest (i.e. any of the 40000 bananas *could* have been in the sample of 100, presumably with equal probability), then the proportion of sampled bananas that are rotten is indeed an unbiased estimator for the proportion of bananas in the whole shipment.

Saying that they should take multiple samples is not really right, because they *did* take multiple samples - 100, in fact. Again, it's not clear how those 100 were chosen, but there's nothing in the wording that explicitly suggests that they just took the first 100 bananas they saw, or picked a single crate of 100 bananas, or anything else.

As to whether it's a "good" estimator, in the absence of any additional information it's probably the best possible estimator available for the chosen sample because you have no other information you could use to improve it. If you know how the sample was selected you can determine the variance of the estimator, and if you know something about the process by which bananas rot you can potentially argue about which sampling method will give better results, but that's all outside the scope of the question.